# Search Bar crashes the app when tapped (iOS Nativescript-Vue)

Tags: ios, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I am trying to add a search bar on my ios app with nativescript-vue.

The problem is that when I tap the search bar, the app stops completely and I can't perform any more tasks since.

On Android it is executing normally.

What I have done on my template:

```
<StackLayout>
    <SearchBar ref="searchBarQuadras" @loaded="hideKeyboard($event)" hint="Search" />
</StackLayout>
<ScrollView height="100%"> ... </ScrollView>
```

Then on my `<script>` tag, I hide the keyboard only for Android:

```
       hideKeyboard(event) {
            let searchBarQuadras = this.$refs.searchBarQuadras;
            if (android) {
                utilsModule.ad.dismissSoftInput(searchBarQuadras);
                event.object.android.clearFocus();
                event.object.android.setFocusable(false);
            }
        },
```

Nothing is made about iOS. Because of that I am finding this behaviour strange.

I am running the app in:

- iPhone 8 plus simulator;
- Nativescript 6.5.0.

So anyone knows or have a clue why the app is crashing/stopping?
I know I am providing few details, but no error or log is generated.

**EDIT** probably the problem is with some simulator config or simulator bug. It works on a real device, as already tested by Manoj.

**EDIT 2 (SOLUTION)** Yep. The problem was with the simulator. After going to **Device > Restart**, the problem was gone.

A few lost hours, but this is the fun of coding!

Comment: What is `android` within if condition in your code. If you haven't declared anything, it can throw error on iOS, it will still work on Android as android will be a namespace there. You just use the boolean variable from platforms module to ensure which platform you are running or use typof operator.

Comment: Hey @Manoj, thanks for your response.
"android" here is declared as 'tns-core-modules/application' and I use it to know if it is android or ios platform. Should it be 'tns-core-modules/platform'? thx

Comment: Yes, you have `isAndroid` variable there. If you still have issues, please share a Playground sample.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I will test the isAndroid variable and then post here.

Comment: I just tested the isAndroid variable, but with no success. Because the 'tns-core-module/platform' can't check for the clearFocus(). This is right, since the page renders on both ios and android. In android it works very well and hides the keyboard when needed (as the code at the post performs this task).

I will prepare a playground sample to reproduce the problem and then I'll post here.

Comment: @Manoj Here is the Playground [link](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=C5LjI3)

Comment: I don't see any crash on iOS.

Comment: Are you using a real device? I am using a simulator. Maybe there is some config that is freezing the simulator?

Comment: I'm using real device.

Comment: Ok. Then should be some config or bug at the simulator..
I was searching here and there are some issues around restarting the simulator, not only a clean app install. Thank you for your time! Best regards. If I find some solution, I will post it here!

Comment: question updated with solution.

Comment: Please don't add unrelated tags: An iOS question should not be tagged [android].

Comment: Ok. Sorry for that. I added the android tag because some nativescript programmer could have passed the same issue and then would know the answer.